# How can i use the CRUD in SharePoint 2010 list by using the SharePoint controls?

Tags: people-picker, application-pages

HI please help me to write custom code to create a custom page using following method.

please let me know how can i use the custom control(I mean the SharePoint User Picker control). Are there any controls available in SharePoint Visual Studio 2010 Kit.

```
if (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
{
    TextField txtField = new TextField();
    txtField.ID = "FieldControlID";
    txtField.FieldName = "FieldControlFieldName";

    DateTimeField dateField = new DateTimeField();
    dateField.ID = "FieldControlID";
    dateField.FieldName = "FieldControlFieldName";

    DropDownChoiceField ddField = new DropDownChoiceField();
    ddField.ID = "FieldControlID";
    ddField.FieldName = "FieldControlFieldName";

    this.Controls.Add(txtField);
    this.Controls.Add(dateField);
    this.Controls.Add(ddField);
}
```

example code above please provide me a full link if some one implement the CURD.

Comment: People that have downvoted havent left a comment (they really should!), so let me elaborate a bit on what to expect from our site: you should **not** expect people to do your job for you. In other words we are glad to give you a nudge in the right direction and assist you in specific problems you might have with SharePoint. However dont expect full code samples ready to insert in your code, so you can call your boss and say "finished" :-)

Comment: Also please ensure you [tag correctly](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-i-use-tags-appropriately) and make sure your questions are easily readable and understandable.

Comment: @Alex  I will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the [PeopleEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor%28v=office.12%29.aspx) control. If you google around, you'll see some examples of it in use in an aspx page, but the principles are the same, it's just a .NET control.